# Get intersecting and overlapping point between two lines in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersection, overlapping-features

I have a line feature class that contains two lines with an overlap and intersecting points. The overlap is circled in the picture. 
[image]

Intersection tool in ArcGIS returns the intersecting point, where two lines cross each other but it is not returning any point at the start of overlap between those two lines.

How can I get all intersecting points and the point where overlapping of two lines start?

Comment: Upload picture where each line has different color. It'll be easier to understand.

Comment: Linear overlap is a slippery slope. If the coordinates fail to match *exactly* (to the coordinate reference resolution) there may be no overlap detected (this is particularly true if the CRs are different).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's not a perfect solution, but you can try use `Feature Vertices to Points` with option **all** to create points at the beginning and end of each line segment.
Then use intersect to get intersecting points.

Closest points from intersecting point are "border" of overlapping area.